# Exclude a user with realm-management role from keycloak's password policy

Tags: keycloak, java-client, password-policy

I have a user with Client Roles realm-management in a realm which contains password policy.
I want to exclude this user from the password policy since I use this user to do some operation fetch the roles get all the user via Java API  and I don't want all the operation to be drop when the password needs to be updated.
I tried to use the admin user from the master realms but I did not get any result

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a realm in keycloak with password policy and you want to exclude the admin user from this policy do this follow these steps :

When a user creates new realm e.g "FooRealm" keycloak adds sibling client inside the master realm with a suffix -realm, in this case, we will see **FooRealm-realm**

1. Inside this client, FooRealm-realm do those changes (settings tab)

   - access type = confidential
   - Standard Flow Enables = ON
   - Direct Access Grants Enables = ON
2. Create user inside the master realm, In user details, go to: Role Mappings >> Clients Roles and from the drop down menu select the sibling client
   (FooRealm-realm) and make sure it is own all the roles inside
3. Now To fetch all the user from the Slave realm FooRealm

   ```
   Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl("http://localhost/auth")
            .realm("master")
            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
            .clientId(FooRealm-realm)
            .clientSecret("7f0080cf-xxxx-xxxxx-9115-xxxxxxxxxx")
            .username("sysadmin")
            .password("x123456")
            .build();
   RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm("FooRealm");

   realmResource.users().list(0, 1000);
   ```